# How can I store Enum value as a String with Hibernate to SQL Server?

Tags: sql, string, hibernate, persistence, enumeration

So I'm having an Enum-property in an Entity bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fileAttachment")
public class FileAttachment

// other properties..

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
FileAttachmentType type;

// getters and setters
```

However, when I persist the bean, the value in that column is shown as a number such as 0 or 1 or 2.

If I `println` the value of the enum just before persisting the bean with EntityManager, the value prints out as String, such as `INVOICE` but in the SQL Server table that row has value 2 for example on the fileAttachmentType-column. What else do I need to configure? I thought the `EnumType.STRING` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Do you create the table in DB by yourself or rely on Hibernate in it?
If first make sure the column type suits for strings storing.
If second try to use annotation like

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "enum('VALUE1','VALUE2')")
```

Comment: It is created by me in an SQL script which is ran by LiquiBase. I posted an answer how I fixed it. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in this case things worked out when I added the annotation:    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)

to the getter of that field and NOT to the actual field.
In another project it works when the annotation is on the field and not anywhere else... so, as far as I comprehed, the answer is the good old "for some reason", but it works now.

If someone would comment the reason for this, I'll update the answer.

EDIT: The reason was found. There was already an annotation on a getter in that Entity class. That's why the annotation on a field didn't work. It happens to be so, that you should either have annotations ONLY on fields OR ONLY on getters. Not annotations on both.